# How to set default file name in PowerPoint template?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I'm creating a series of PowerPoint templates.  When opening these .potx files, a default file name of "Presentation1", "Presentation2", etc. is in the window title. I want to replace this with something more descriptive.  Is this possible?

Comment: Name the templates?

Comment: The templates are named (something like YEAR_SPEAKERNAME.potx), but still when you double click the template, the new window says "Presentation1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is hard-wired into PowerPoint. You can't really change it.

One possible workaround:

Open your POTX, save it as a PPTX named as you want it to appear, then set it to read-only. To create a new presentation, open it, save as a PPTX under a new name.

If you or someone you know is moderately proficient with VBA, you could create an add-in that traps the new file event and automatically saves the default-named file to some new name, possibly even something based on the name of the template file you've doubleclicked.